# Manipulate Discrete Values Labelling

Tags: plotting, manipulate, formatting

I have 3 lists of plots (generated in other code), `rawplots`, `weightplots`,`linearizedplots`.

Each list of plots is the same length, and I wanted to use `Manipulate` to access one plot at a time. I attempted to use the following:

`Manipulate[plot[[n]], {plot, {rawplots, weightplots,linearizedplots}, PopupMenu}, {n, 1, Length@files, 1,RadioButtonBar}]`

This works, but in the Popup Menu I have plots. I would like to instead have words in the popup menu.

Additionally, I have a variable `files` which is a list of filenames. Ideally, I would like to have the radio buttons named `files[[n]]`, i.e. the file name from the variable `files`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use value -> label in the list of values:

```
Manipulate[
    plot[[n]],
    {plot, {rawplots -> "foo", weightplots -> "bar", linearizedplots -> "baz"}, PopupMenu}
]
```